# linux - signal not passed to multi-command

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Im trying to understand why signals arent being passed properly under this setup.
Simple test, I have a python script that registers a sigterm handler and prints if it gets it.  I have verified this works if i run it and send a TERM.

However, I happen to be running this as a python Subprocess with useShell = True.  useShell launches the command with /bin/sh -c ...

If I do this, it actually works as well:

```
$/bin/sh -c "python ~/tmpcode/signal_test.py" &
[8] 6207
$ kill 6207
 signum 15
```

However, I have scripts that do chained commands, ie /foo/bar.sh; some_other_script.py.  Under this scenario, the signal is *not* passed to the final script:

```
$ /bin/sh -c "echo foo; python ~/tmpcode/signal_test.py" &
[8] 8015
$ kill 8015
```

Same thing happens if I try && instead of ;
Im trying to understand whats going on here, and if there is a way to get the signal to chain through.
Side point: The main reason the script is running multi-chain commands is because the first command sets up some environment for the second one to use.

signal_test.py:

```
import time
import signal
import sys

def handler( signum, frame ):
    print( "signum %d\n" % signum ) 
    sys.exit(signum)

signal.signal( signal.SIGTERM, handler )
time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: That is because Python process will have a different process id.

Comment: @user902384 That doesn't explain how `signal_test.py` gets the signal in the first question.

Comment: But in the first example, `sh` may be optimized to use `exec` to run the single specified command, meaning 6207 *is* the Python process. In the second example, `sh` is instead forking a new process for Python. (If you show the contents of `signal_test.py`, we could probably suggest how to confirm this hypothesis.)

Comment: Might also help to see `ps -fu $LOGNAME`, and maybe `trap`.

Comment: As others have said the python process will be on another PID. If you can't easily get your hands on this PID you could perhaps use pkill or killall, might help to wrap the call to python in a script with a known name if going down this route, assuming you don't want to killall python ...

Comment: @chepner There are two things here. Shell process and Python process. In first one there is only Python process forking but in second process two different processes are happening. shell and python and thus it signal does not get transferred to python. If I really need that then I will setup environment in Python itself.

Comment: @user902384 I'm claiming there *aren't* two processes in the first example. Instead of forking, `sh` is simply `exec`ing the Python process. There is also no requirement that I am aware of that a process pass signals on to its children.

Comment: @ByteMe95 How does `kill 6207` (which sends SIGTERM to a process) get processed by your script (which only installs a handler for SIGKILL)?

Comment: @chepner I am sorry about writing fork. My system programming days are kind of behind me. Yes it will be an exec call. Cannot edit comment.

Comment: @chepner good catch, that was actually SIGTERM when I tested.

Comment: I think the main question here is, what does ";" actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain the details.

## The number bash returned is not pid, it is pgid (process group id)

When you run a command in the shell, shell will create a new process group. The group will contain all process in the command. And the pgid is the same as pid of the leader process.

A process group means task in the word multi-task, shell is able to switch between groups using bg(^Z)/fg. All signal (like ^C) generated by shell (acturaly pty, another story) will send to the entire group instead of leader process.

## When shell creates multiple processes or single process ?

The answer is obviously, the shell will create multiple processes when the commands can't be handled by a single process.

#### In the first example

```
$/bin/sh -c "python ~/tmpcode/signal_test.py" &
[8] 6207
```

a single command is issued, so the sub-shell itself (`/bin/sh`) becomes `python`. Notes, even there is only one process, there still be a new process group containing the only process.

#### In the second example

```
$ /bin/sh -c "echo foo; python ~/tmpcode/signal_test.py" &
[8] 8015
```

two commands are issued, the task can't be achieved by a single process, so multiple process is needed:

```
/bin/sh
    echo
    python
```

A process group is created containing these three process.

## How to send signals to process group ?

Use

```
kill <SIGNAL> -<pgid>
```

The minus sign in front of pgid is essential.

Comment: I don't think there's any requirement that the shell detect when it could simply `exec` rather than forking; that's an implementation-dependent optimization  (which could be confirmed using `strace` or the like).

Comment: @chepner maybe my answer is a bit misleading, but my point is that you should always treat the number as pgid instead of pid. I don't care about how many process are there at all.

Comment: Fair enough. Sending a signal to a process group means that each process receives the signal directly from the OS, though, rather than the group leader passing it to its children, right? (A subtle distinction, but it would mean, among other things, the group leader doesn't get to decide who receives the signal.)